# jquerymobile scroll api does not work on dynamically added element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, scroll

I am using [this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html) javascript to add scroll to my dynamically added DIV element

But it's not working

If I add DIV element statically then it works correctly

Please help me..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function? I haven't used in mobile apps, but it binds all current and future elements. It should do the trick.

Comment: @john..but how could i add live function to my scroll function

Comment: I recommend reading: http://api.jquery.com/live/